# Apk Upload Failed

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to update my application since yesterday (5/3/14) but i can not. I added a higher version code and a higher version number than the previous application but nothing happened. This screenshots shows my problem.

What can i do?

Let me show you my **AndroidManifest.xml** too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package=""
    android:versionCode="19"
    android:versionName="3" >


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

   <receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action 
                    android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget" />
        </receiver>




    <receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider2" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action 
                    android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget2" />
        </receiver>




    <receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider3" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action 
                    android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget3" />
        </receiver>

         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>



        <activity
            android:name="gr.backatel.rootchecker.RootChecker"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            </activity>

          <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />


        <activity android:name=".stage1" android:label="Check for Root"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".moreinfo"   android:label="@string/info">

        </activity>

         <activity android:name=".settings" android:label="Themes">

         </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

When i am trying to update my app!!

Using **mobile browser:**

[image]

**Screeshot : on Mozilla**

[image: ScreenShot:]

**Screenshot on Chrome:**

[image]

When progress is 99% nothing happens  in the end.
Using mobile shows the error that upload failed

I tried to sing out and sign back but nothing changed.

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: Did you check your package name?

Comment: So, it never finishes to 100%?

Comment: no it never finishes... and i have checked my package name!

Comment: 1) check package name of your new apk with the current apk at google play store, they must be same. 2) check if the signature is same. 3) check if the version code of new apk is greater than current apk at store.

Comment: yes i have already checked that

Comment: It kind of sounds like a problem on Google's end. They should be able to be more specific about the problem if it was something you did wrong. Is it still not working? How big is your APK?

Comment: Still does not work. My apk size is 1,5mb

Comment: It would probably be too much hassle if you are only Google, to show developers a small hint on why they cannot upload their apk instead of leaving them in the dark...

Answer (score 2):

just log out and back in or  use firefox instead of chrome. That should actually solve your problem...

Answer (score 2):

I can now confirm that there is an issue uploading applications at the moment, there are a lot of people having issues, Google are looking into it now, and it should be fixed shortly.

Comment: as of today (right now) it should be sorted, if this was the correct answer, please mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

try recompiling your app.

After that, clean the cache of the browser. Try using a different browser if nothing has changed

Comment: Have you clean the cache? Did you recompile the App? Have you disabled Proguard?

Comment: I deleted the apk and exported a new signed apk. How can i disable proguard?

Comment: Ok...if you don't know how to disable proguard, you probably didn't enabled it...I think it isn't an APK problem. May be something due to internet connection. Could try to connect the pc to another connection such as tethering trough the smartphone? When the apk isn't ok, google shows to you an error to end.

Comment: DONT disable proguard! It does not change the Manifest, which is what the playstore needs in the end.

Comment: Did you use the same keystore to sign your app?

Comment: recompile your app,clean and rebuild,check on device then change the version which is above the current version on store.check pkg name and lint warnings too.some time it happens due to lint warnings also.check error log in Eclipse and fix them if there is any.i am sure you are able to upload. also don't uncheck  Project -> properties, find Android Lint Preferences, in top to right click configure workspace settings... -> click "Run full error check when exporting app", apply done

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `android:debuggable="false"` inside `<application>` tag

Comment: unfortunately the problem still remains

Answer (score 1):

Some things you can try:

1. Unpublish your app, wait for a while, upload your apk, then republish the app.
2. Use a different connection or a system, if that is what the problem is.
3. Add one of your friend OR another email of yours as a release manager and try uploading from his id.
4. Clear your browser cache, cookies, temp files etc and retry.
5. Just use a different name for the APK.

Do let me know if any of these work.

Answer (score 1):

Upload for beta testing.  After you have successfully downloaded your app from beta and you are certain it works correctly publish to production.  See [Beta testing and staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) for details.

Comment: Sorry @noobProgrammer something is really really wrong.  That was the only thing I could think of that wasn't already in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware google play services are fine, I uploaded an APK not too long ago and it all went okay, but that being said there could always be an issue with the google servers, however here are a few things you can try.

Examine your project by using Android Lint tool for any omissions and errors. To find out about lint see this link:

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

Also, you could use the aapt tool, included in the Android SDK, to process your application, based on its declared features and permissions. To do so, run aapt with the dump badging command. It will parse your application's manifest and apply the same rules as used by Google Play to determine the features that your application requires. You can view more on this here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#testing

Comment: how can i use aapt tool

Comment: There is a link already in there for the aapt tool, also google will be best for you. Also, it might be worth contacting Google, My application is also failing to upload and there could be a problem with a few of the servers.